Polarimeter Working(Bi Quartz)
Can somebody clear this confusion of mine why do we take reading only on tint of passage in bi quartz polarimeter and why tint of passage is violet in color not any other color. Please explain in detail manner (if possible prove it through math and physics).And also one more thing in bi quartz polarimeter one more point occurs where both hemispheres seen through polarimeter is yellow (can we take reading on that point for specific rotation of a compound) and also explain why at that point both hemispheres are yellow(through math and physics).

The quartz plate that is placed in your bi quartz is special because it is composed of two half plates. One is a left quartz and the other is a right quartz. The left/right means that the polarization of the incident light is rotated in a direction or another depending on the type of the quartz.
Let's say that we use a white light source for our experiment.
The incident white light with propagation direction $z$ is passed through a polarizer with a transmission axis along $x$. Thus, the incident polarization on the quartz plates is $\vec{E}_i=E_x\vec{e}_x=(1,0)^T$ (see figure below). In the first time, let's consider a quartz plate with a separation axis along $x$.
This polarization is rotated by the quartz plates because the quartz is optically active. Because the incident polarization and the separation axis are parallel, the rotations due to each quartz (right and left) are symmetric.
Now, let's consider the polarization of the light after its passage through the left quartz for example. The polarization has turned by an angle $\alpha$ with respect to the $x$ axis. The angle $\alpha$ is a function of the wavelength $\lambda$ and the thickness $e$ of the quartz plate. You observe a violet tint of passage on your screen because the quartz plates are manufactured that way, with a specific thickness such that the yellow radiation turns by 90° degrees. It is a choice, because our eye is sensitive to this extinction, allowing better precision on the measures I suppose.

On the picture, $P$ is the polarizer, $A$ the analyzer and $B$ is the bi quartz plate. The several arrows on the bi quartz plate describe the rotation of the polarization associated to a given wavelength $\lambda$. The arrows $j$ and $j'$ described yellow light. You see that the polarization of the yellow light is perpendicular to the analyzer.
If now you put an optical medium between the polarizer and the bi quartz plate, the polarization incident on your bi quartz isn't $\vec{E}_i=(1,0)^T$ anymore; the direction of polarization and the bi quartz separation direction aren't parallel anymore. So you'll observe different colors on both hemispheres with different intensities. To know the value of the optical activity, you just turn the bi quartz+analyzer to have the tint of passage on your screen.
$\textbf{The maths}$
The incident polarization $\vec{E}_i=(1,0)^T$ can be decomposed on the basis of the circular polarization i.e.,
\begin{equation}
\vec{E}_i=(1,i)^T+(1,-i)^T=\vec{E}_R+\vec{E}_L
\end{equation}
For an optical active medium, the eigenstates are circular polarization. By eigenstate, I mean the polarization that aren't modified by the medium after propagation. If $J$ is the Jones matrix of the medium, and $\vec{E}_{inc}=(1,\pm i)^T$ is the incident polarization, the polarization state after the medium is given by,
\begin{equation}
\vec{E}_{out}=J\vec{E}_{inc}=c_{r,l}\vec{E}_{inc}
\end{equation}
where $c_{r,l}$ is the eigenvalue associated to $\vec{E}_i$ being right or left circular.
The two eigenstates have different "eigenvalues" and these eigenvalues represent the speed of propagation of right/left circular polarization in the medium. Therefore, for our $\vec{E}_i=(1,0)^T$ parallel to $x$, the exit polarization is given by,
\begin{equation}
\vec{E}_{out}=c_r\vec{E}_R+c_l\vec{E}_L
\end{equation}
This equation means that there is a phase shift between these two polarization states at the exit of the medium. This phase shift is given by,
\begin{equation}
\varphi=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}(n_R-n_L)e
\end{equation}
where $n_L$ and $n_R$ are the refractives indices for left/right circular polarization respectively. You can show that the field $\vec{E}_{out}$ can be written as,
\begin{equation}
\vec{E}_{out}=e^{i\theta}\vec{E}_R+e^{-i\theta}\vec{E}_L=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)^T
\end{equation}
where $\theta=\varphi/2$. The last equation tells you that the polarization is still linear but not along $x$ anymore. It has rotated.
In the case of the bi quartz plate, the thickness is chosen so that the angle $\theta=\pi/2$ at that wavelength.
When you insert an optical active medium, the electric field after the bi quartz is given by,
\begin{equation}
\vec{E}_{out}=J_{bi}J_{m}\vec{E}_{in}
\end{equation}
After the optical active medium, the polarization is still linear but has rotated by an angle $\theta_m$. If now you make coincide the axis of vibration of this polarization with the separation of your bi quartz, you'll recover the violet tint.

So why do i see a position where both hemisphere turns yellow with almost same intensity?

With an optical active medium placed in the polarimeter ?

I am seeing that position after placing optical medium and without it also but the position differs.

Do you see the violet tint of passage ?

Yes i do see violet(tint of passage).But i am asking why there is some another position  where both hemsipheres turn yellow of same intensity.

If the color you see is a bright yellow, I don't know the answer. But if the color is a pale yellow or green/yellow it simply means that you analyzer and the separation axis  of the bi quartz are perpendicular

Basically the analyzer axis is aligned near to the plane of polarization of yellow light?Does this position has any significance or its just its just random.

Look at the figure I posted. In this configuration you have the violet tint. But now, if you rotate the analyzer (or the polarizer) such that it makes an angle of 90 degrees with the separation axis of the bi quartz, you see a pale yellow tint with equal intensity in both quartz plates

yes I am saying that only.

It means that the polarization has been rotated by 90 degrees by the medium

yes it was nearly about 90 degrees only.
